# Create playwright tests to run in sequence

Tags: javascript, typescript, playwright

I need help wit my code. I'm trying to create test in playwright that will go on forgot password page, create new password and after that will try to log in with that new password, but I have issue with return value.
Here is my code below and if someone knows how to fix it to work, it would be great.

```
async createNewPassword(email: string) {
    const { faker } = await require("@faker-js/faker");
    const password = faker.internet.password();
    await this.forgot_password_email_field.fill(email);
    const email_field = await this.forgot_password_email_field.inputValue();
    await this.forgot_password_field.fill(password);
    const new_password = await this.forgot_password_field.inputValue();
    await this.forgot_password_confirm_field.fill(new_password);
    await this.forgot_password_save_button.click();
    console.log(new_password);
    return new_password;
  }

  async loginNewPassword(email: string) {
    let new_login_password = this.createNewPassword();
    console.log(new_login_password);
    await this.email_field.fill(email);
    await this.password_field.fill(await new_login_password);
    await this.login_button.click();
  }
```

I don't know how to catch that new_password from "createNewPassword" function and to use it in "loginNewPassword" function.

I tried with this to catch up that return value, but no luck

```
let new_login_password = this.createNewPassword();
```

Comment: Your code should be fine, other than logging the promise at `console.log(new_login_password);` since you only `await` it later, with `this.password_field.fill(await new_login_password);`. You probably meant `const new_login_password = await this.createNewPassword();`, then remove the later `await` so your `console.log` will show the password rather than the promise.

Answer (score 0):

In your loginNewPassword method, you are missing `await` before `this.createNewPassword()`.

```
async loginNewPassword(email: string) {
    let new_login_password = await this.createNewPassword();
    console.log(new_login_password);
    await this.email_field.fill(email);
    await this.password_field.fill(await new_login_password);
    await this.login_button.click();
}
```

Comment: OP is awaiting the promise already, just not in the `console.log`. If you `await this.createNewPassword()` there's no need to `await new_login_password`.

Comment: Perfect, it's working now. Thanks a lot.
I have one more question, since method "async createNewPassword(email: string)" expecting email as an argument now this line of code "let new_login_password = await this.createNewPassword();" in " loginNewPassword" method is showing this error
"(method) ForgotPasswordPage.createNewPassword(email: string): Promise<string>
Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554)
ForgotPasswordPage.ts(46, 27): An argument for 'email' was not provided."

Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

you need to await value returned from it before continue to the next line of code

Comment: Perfect, it's working now. Thanks a lot. I have one more question, since method "async createNewPassword(email: string)" expecting email as an argument now this line of code "let new_login_password = await this.createNewPassword();" in " loginNewPassword" method is showing this error "(method) ForgotPasswordPage.createNewPassword(email: string): Promise<string> Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554) ForgotPasswordPage.ts(46, 27): An argument for 'email' was not provided." Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: how did u provided an argument for " loginNewPassword" method
it seem that y didn't give correct argument to it